# Salesforce Marketing Cloud Rest API : Interactions endpoint is forbidden

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I have been trying to do curl request to hit journey endpoint :

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer **Token**' -A 'Jersey/2.25.1' 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?page=1'
```

I get the following error :

```
{"message":"You do not have access to this object.","errorcode":20000,"documentation":""}
```

I have given the read permissions but not still getting the forbidden exception. Is there any change in REST API Structure ? If not what could be the possible case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the user identified have access to Journey Builder App in the UI?  If not, ensure that the user has the correct permissions to access.

Comment: The user has admin access and had manually given read permissions. But is it possible to not have access to Journey Builder App in the UI even with admin level access ?

Comment: Yes it is if the Permissions for the user has them set to Deny. You can check it by checking permissions with when you look at he roles for a user to verify that isn't the issue.